# What LaTeX package to use with knitr to get more table-control? tabu?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I’m writing a longer table with knitr using `xtable` and the `tabular.environment='longtable'` in the longtable package when `print`ing  them in my `.Rnw`-file, problem is that I can’t control the longtable environment enough.

I have some text I would like to have left-justified and hyphenated in a certain way inside the table (i.e. I have some cells with quite a lot of text)

Any advice on how I could do this? What packages would you recommend? Anyone tried the `tabu` package?

What I am mainly looking for is a way to justify my text in a nice way inside my table. Something along the lines of this,

[image]

Comment: That is basically a `xtable` question. Maybe there is an option in `?print.xtable` but I have never tried an example like this, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm (as maintainer of `xtable`) that no backslashes are needed. I have updated the documentation of `xtable` on R-Forge.

A couple of notes:

There is an example of the use of fixed width alignments in the `xtable` Gallery vignette.

Also, a slightly simpler specification works, namely, `align = "llp{5cm}"`

Answer (score 1):

`xtable` has parameter `align`; for your example, try

```
 align=c("l","l","l","p\{5cm\"})
```

**Edited** (after checking @Alex A. comment):
The \before the last " was definitively wrong, but this time I checked carefully. Looks like the following version without any backslashes is correct. I will report the error in the docs to the package author.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<a, results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
x  = data.frame(a=1:10,
     b=rep("This is a very long text that takes up to much space",10),
     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

xt = xtable(x, align=c("l","l","p{5cm}"))
print(xt, include.rownames=FALSE)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you have your closing quotation mark in the wrong spot in the last string. The backslash should be escaping the close bracket, not the quotation mark, right? So shouldn't it be `"p\{5cm\}"`?

Comment: Actually, don't you need double backslashes? `"p\\{5cm\\}"`?