# xtable: extra column added and error using align argument

Tags: r, xtable

I'm having a hard time generating the LaTex format table I want using the xtable package.  There are three things I'm trying to do:

1. Not have the first column be the simply the numbered rows.
2. Have the columns be a fixed width.
3. Use the longtable environment because it is a large table.

Here is the object I'm trying to export as a LaTex table:

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(23L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 14L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 15L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 24L, 25L, 28L, 29L, 27L, 26L, 16L, 1L), .Label = c("age.cat", 
"ALQ101", "BMXBMI", "BMXHT", "BMXWT", "CBD070", "CBD090", "CBD110", 
"CBD120", "CBD130", "DMDBORN4", "DMDEDUC2", "DMDMARTL", "DMQMILIZ", 
"INDHHIN2", "is.obese", "PAD680", "PAQ710", "PAQ715", "RIAGENDR", 
"RIDAGEYR", "RIDRETH3", "SEQN", "SMQ020", "SMQ680", "weight.status", 
"WHD140", "WHQ030", "WHQ040"), class = "factor"), Description = structure(c(25L, 
10L, 1L, 9L, 18L, 7L, 8L, 17L, 3L, 29L, 12L, 6L, 11L, 20L, 24L, 
23L, 22L, 21L, 19L, 14L, 13L, 27L, 28L, 15L, 16L, 26L, 5L, 4L, 
2L), .Label = c("Age", "Age Range", "Annual Hld Income", "BMI Based Obesity Status", 
"BMI Based Weight Category", "Body Mass Index", "Country of Birth", 
"Education Level", "Ethnicity", "Gender", "Had at Least 12 Drinks in Past Year", 
"Height (cm)", "Hours Computer Use Per Day", "Hours Watch TV Per Day", 
"How Do You Consider Your Weight", "Like to Weight More, Less, or Same", 
"Marital Status", "Military Service", "Minutes Sedentary Activity Per Day", 
"Money Spent at Supermarket/Grocery Stores", "Money Spent on Carryout/Delivered Foods", 
"Money Spent on Eating Out", "Money Spent on Food at Other Stores", 
"Money Spent on Non-Food Items", "Respondent Sequence Number", 
"Self Reported Greatest Weight (Pounds)", "Smoked at Least 100 Cigarettes in Life", 
"Used Tobacco/Nicotine in Last 5 Days", "Weight (kg)"), class = "factor"), 
    Values = structure(c(1L, 8L, 20L, 10L, 26L, 25L, 7L, 9L, 
    2L, 21L, 23L, 19L, 26L, 17L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 14L, 6L, 
    5L, 26L, 26L, 12L, 11L, 22L, 24L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("", 
    "0-4999, 5000-9999, 10000-14999, 15000-19999, 20000-24999, 25000-34999, 35000-44999, 45000-54999, 55000-64999, 65000-74999, Over 20000, Under 20000, 75000-99999, 100000 and over", 
    "0: No, 1: Yes", "20 – 29, 30 – 39, 40 – 49, 50 – 59, 60 – 69, 70 – 79, Over 80", 
    "Less than 1 Hour, 1 Hour, 2 Hours, 3 Hours, 4 Hours, 5 Hours or More, Does Not Use Computer Outside Work/School", 
    "Less than 1 Hour, 1 Hour, 2 Hours, 3 Hours, 4 Hours, 5 Hours or More, Does Not Watch TV", 
    "Less than 9th grade, 9-11, High School Graduate/GED, Some college or AA degree, College Graduate or Above", 
    "Male, Female", "Married, Widowed, Diviced, Separated, Never Married, Living with Partner", 
    "Mexican-American, Other-Hispanic, Non-Hispanic White, Non-Hispanic Black, Non-Hispanic Asian, Other", 
    "More, Less, Same", "Overweight, Underweight, About Right", 
    "Range of Values 0 – 1071", "Range of Values 0 – 1380", "Range of Values 0 – 2142", 
    "Range of Values 0 – 3000", "Range of Values 0 – 5142", "Range of Values 0 – 8142", 
    "Range of Values 12.4 – 82.1", "Range of Values 20 - 80", 
    "Range of Values 3.6 - 216.1", "Range of Values 75 – 550", 
    "Range of values 82 – 204.5", "Underweight, Normal, Overweight, Obese", 
    "United States, Other", "Yes, No"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", 
"Description", "Values"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-29L))
```

If I simply use the command `xtable(df)`, I get a four column table where the first column is simply numbering the rows.  How can I not do this?

EDIT: I've been informed of a typo in the linked solution.  I've fixed it here, but I still get the same error.

I know xtable has an align argument, but when I use (copied from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664365/what-latex-package-to-use-with-knitr-to-get-more-table-control-tabu))

```
xtable(df, align=c("l","l","l","p\{5cm\}"))
```

I get an error:

```
\{ is an urecognized escape in character string starting ""p\{".
```

I've tried using a double backslash, but that doesn't work either.

Once I get the first two issues straightened out, I believe the command is simply `print(df, tabular.environment = "longtable")`, correct?

Comment: There's actually a typo in the answer to the linked question: the last string should be `"p\{5cm\}"` according to the documentation for `xtable()`. Otherwise you have unmatched quotes.

Comment: I fixed that typo in my code, using `xtable(df, align=c("l","l","l","p{5cm}"))` and I still got the same error.

Comment: Are your brackets escaped? I can't tell without the code formatting (using backticks).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what "are your brackets escaped?" means.  I edited my reply to use backticks for code formatting.  I don't know why the backslashes are missing from my original post and from my reply, but they're in my code.

Comment: Are your brackets escaped --> Do you have backslashes preceding the open and close curly brackets, i.e. `\{` and `\}`. Sorry, I should have been clearer.

Comment: In my code, yes, I do.  I don't know why they don't appear here.

EDIT: I replaced single backslash with a double and I'm no longer getting an error.  Still don't know how to get rid of the first column other than manually deleting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the error, use two backslashes in the `align` string, like so:

```
xtable(df, align=c("l", "l", "l", "p\\{5cm\\}"))
```

Your data frame doesn't have row names, which are included by default when printing an `xtable` object, so it uses row numbers. To avoid this, use `include.rownames=FALSE` in the `print()` function.

```
print(xtable(df, align=c("l", "l", "l", "p\\{5cm\\}")),
      include.rownames=FALSE,
      tabular.environment="longtable")
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you! Still having problems compiling the pdf using knitr, but that's a problem for a different thread (and different day).  Thanks again!

Comment: @MikeEdinger: Glad I could help! If you're having trouble on the knitr side, you might be able to get a better answer on the TeX Stack Exchange site than on Stack Overflow.